# Unable to Open STS on linux mint 17

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, 64-bit, spring-tool-suite

Few Days ago I was able to open and Use my STS (Spring Tool Suite) on my linux mint 17 system. I also made sure that all the applications and java were of the 64 bit configuration.

Scenario happening: On Double Clicking the STS file a grey rectangular box pops up and then nothing happens. Tried installing new version but the result is the same.

Here is my java version and details:

`java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)`

and here is the STS.ini file details, I have no idea why this is happening suddenly

```
`-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Xverify:none
-Xmx1200m`
```

Any help on the same will be helpful!!

Comment: Have you tried starting the STS from a terminal? You may see the cause there.

Comment: Yes @AlejandroAlanis I have used the command `./STS` no change a grey block appears and nothing starts up!!

Comment: did you try to start STS from the command line with the "-clean" option? Maybe that helps.

Comment: Well @MartinLippert it may sound weird, but I got it working after 5th attempt of shutting down the system, starting it, double clicking the app continuously. After that it was working fine without any further attempts.

Comment: That sounds indeed weird, but nevertheless glad to hear that you got it working... :-)